# Whitespace encoding using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Tags: objective-c

I am encoding white spaces in a string using

```
[@"iPhone Content.doc" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

in SKPSMTP message sending. But while receiving mail at attachments place I am getting the name `iPhone%20Content.doc` - instead of a space it shows `%20`. How can this be avoided / correctly encoded?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` then you're going to get percent signs in your result string... You can either use something different, or go back through and remove the percent signs later.

From the doc:

> **`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`** Returns a representation of
>   the receiver using a given encoding to determine the percent escapes
>   necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string.

aka, "this method adds percent signs". If you want to reverse this process, use `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`

Just a side note, `%20` is there because the hex representation of the space character is 20 and the % sign is an escape. You only need to do this for URLs, as they disallow the use of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for my question. Actually am missed to set the "" to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the remote receiver can not accept the url with whitespace, so we must convert the URL address using the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` function.

This function replaces spaces in the URL expression with %20. It is especially useful when the URL contains non-ascii characters - you have use the function to percent-escape the URL so that the remote server can accept your request.