# Why to use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding?

Tags: ios, url, nsstring

I am new to iOS programming . I just want to know the practical example of

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding
```

i.e why and when to use ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968929/whitespace-encoding-using-stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding

Comment: Because when Calling Service with Space then got an error in ios. but using above method convert space to %20 in URL . so you can got response. otherwise got an error.

Comment: @Kirti is it like the receiver expect that it should be in such format ? & if yes then if i do it manually by appending something else like ## will it work ?

Answer (score 2):

[`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) is useful when working with URL. It returns a percent escapes string that is a legal URL string.

It will convert "http://www.example.com/resources?name=hello world" to "http://www.example.com/resources?name=hello%20world"

Here is more details about URL http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Note: this method is deprecated in iOS 9. You might also want to look at using this method [`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) if you want to use UTF-8 encoding.

I added the code to show the error when send the url to the server without encoding.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/test/test.php?name=hello world";

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                NSURLResponse *response,
                NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            } else {
                NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"%@",newStr);
            }
        }] resume];
```

This code returns

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x7f92f17989d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f92f141b1f0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1002.)"}`

So, to fix the error. We just need to encode the urlString like this

`[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]`

Comment: Thank you @thanyaj . I got little bit but still it's not clear to me why i need to do so ?

Comment: If you don't use it, it return error like this   
 `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x7fa1c99924a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa1c992c940 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1002.)"}`

Answer (score 1):

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` will convert the Unicode* character to the percent escape format.

`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` will do the opposite, convert the percent escape to the Unicode*.

*Actually not Unicode, but the encoding you choose.

[This is a good example that you are looking for](http://cybersam.com/ios-dev/proper-url-percent-encoding-in-ios)

Comment: This doesn't answer why. You should include that in your answer rather than a link

Comment: This is what it does. But i want to know why is it necessary?